# undefined variables in loop with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So my problem is with the timeout,
because by the time it starts my array is reset and also all the other values are changed as well.

i have user input in the messages array, which are the lines they entered.
for example:

```
messages = ["first line", "second", "third", "etc.."];

for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++){
    setTimeout(function () {
        draw(messages[i], x, y+(i*k*f) );
    }, i*20*messages[i].length);
}
message = "";
messages = [];
```

`k` and `f` are constant values `3` and `2` respectively, but they can be changed by the user to whatever float value. `x` and `y` are some coordinates.

So once the `draw()` function is called the values are undefined or wrong.

I've searched some answers, but none were similar enough for me to figure out what I need to do for my particular case.

Comment: Don’t reset your `messages` array until your timeout call runs. That is, reset it in the timed out function.

Answer (score 7):

Your for loop executes 4 times based on the example `messages` length. However by the time the first `setTimeout` ends and the anonymous function inside of it fires, the `messages` array is already empty by the lines of code that follow at the end.

In that last line of code, you are re-initializing the `messages` array to the empty array and by the time the asynchronous `setTimeout` callbacks occur, they are trying to access indices 0,1,2,3 which no longer exist, thus undefined values are the result.

```
messages = []; // an empty array with zero length
```

To help clarify what's happening, consider this:

```
// this is what you might expect
var arr = [ "foo", "bar", "baz"];
console.log(arr[0]); // logs "foo" to the console

// this is actually what's happening
var arr = []; // set arr equal to a new empty array
console.log(arr[0]); // logs "undefined" to the console
```

I’ve only explained the what and why. 
@brk provides a couple of code solutions in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript `setTimeout` function is asynchronous. so your following code

```
messages = [];
```

it gets executed before the actual timeout callback function gets called and you see the error because the `messages` variable is empty when the actual callback function is called.

try to learn more about asynchronous Javascript, you will understand better.

Answer (score 2):

Create a closure and an immediately invoking function expression and pass the variable to access it inside the settimeout callback function

```js
let messages = ["first line", "second", "third", "etc.."];

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  //Creating an IIFE
  (function(x, msg) {
    //typical closure, passing x & message to the settimeout
    setTimeout(function() {
      draw(msg[x]);
    }, x * 20 * msg[x].length);
  }(i, messages)) // passing reference of both i, & messages
}
messages = "";
messages = [];

function draw(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

An alternate to this usage of `let` keyword. Variable declared with let keyword always have scope in current block

```js
let messages = ["first line", "second", "third", "etc.."];

for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  let _i = i,
    _ms = messages
  setTimeout(function() {
    draw(_ms[_i]);
  }, _i * 20 * _ms[_i].length);
}
messages = "";
messages = [];

function draw(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer because you didn't just say what the problem was, you addressed it with a couple of workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run you logic inside `setTimeout` and variable `i` is function level. That means you timeout function will execute after for loop and all sync method finish. In your case your timeout function will execute after `messages=[]` last line and value of `i` will be `messages.length` which is `4` while loop executing.

To prevent this issue use self closure function. Self closure will take parameters as sync and will store variable function level which will not change.

Here's a example how to use self closure.

```
messages = ["first line", "second", "third", "etc.."];

for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++){
    (function(i, message) {
       setTimeout(function () {
          draw(message, x, y+(i*k*f) );
       }, i*20*message.length);
    })(i, messages[i])
}
message = "";
messages = [];
```

In this example we are avoiding use of variable of foor loop function and we are creating new function inside loop and passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the current value.

The main problem is `variable's scope` and shared variable be overrided.

```js
messages = ["first line", "second", "third", "etc.."];

// your variable
var x = 1;
var y = 1;
var k = 2;
var f = 3;

for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++){
  set(messages[i]);
}
message = "";
messages = [];

// set a function scope to save current value
function set(val){
  setTimeout(function () {
      draw(val, x, y+(i*k*f) );
  }, i*20*val.length);
}

// your draw function
function draw(a, b, c){
  console.log(a);
}
```